# Understanding 'local' column in the output of "ntpd -c peers"

Tags: linux, ntp

Running NTP v4.1.2.
I configured a couple of random addresses as NTP servers. 
This was the output to 'ntpdc -c peers':

```
         remote           local      st poll reach  delay   offset    disp
     =======================================================================
     =10.1.1.1        10.16.44.10      3   64    7 0.23164 -0.001340 1.93799
     =1.1.1.1         0.0.0.5         16   64    0 0.00000  0.000000 0.00000
     =1.2.2.2         0.0.0.5         16   64    0 0.00000  0.000000 0.00000
     =10.16.58.29     10.16.44.10      3   64    7 0.00151  0.008174 1.93797
```

Then I restarted the system and got the following :

```
        remote           local      st poll reach  delay   offset    disp
   =======================================================================
   =10.1.1.1        0.0.0.0          3   64    1 0.23166  0.210462 7.93750
   =1.1.1.1         0.0.0.5         16   64    0 0.00000  0.000000 0.00000
   =1.2.2.2         0.0.0.5         16   64    0 0.00000  0.000000 0.00000
   =10.16.58.29     0.0.0.0          3   64    1 0.00169  0.218482 7.93750
```

Can someone please help me understand the behavior of NTP using this? 
What does the 'local' column represent? Why did the output get altered after reload? i.e. Why did the address become 0.0.0.0 and not my IP after a reload?

Answer (score 0):

The local column lists the current system peer of the remote time server. Your address should not appear under the local column unless you have configured a symmetric peering set up for your host and the remote server.  In addition to IP addresses the column could also show something like `GPS` or `PPS` to indicate a locally attached reference clock